# Choose smallest value from lists given same coordinates in 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I have two lists:

```
a = [[9, 5], [9, 10000], [9, 10000], [5, 10000], [5, 10000], [10001, 10], [10001, 10]]
b = [19144.85, 8824.73, 26243.88, 23348.02, 40767.17, 55613.43, 40188.8]
```

I am trying to remove the repeated coordinates in a and remove the adjacent value in b but by leaving the smallest value. So for example coordinate [9,10000] is repeated twice with values in b of 8824.73 and 26243.88 the result should be two lists where there is only one [9,10000] with the smaller of b which is 8824.73.

So overall the result should look like:

```
aa = [[9,5],[9,10000],[5,10000],[10001,10]]
bb = [19144.85, 8824.73, 23348.02, 40188.8]
```

I am finding it difficult to formulate the problem and iterate through the lists and I am not sure how I can use the zip function. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you open to using 3rd party libraries (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), or are you looking for a pure Python solution?

Comment: Does the result need to have the same order as the original list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an O(*n*) solution using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for (key1, key2), value in zip(a, b):
    dd[(key1, key2)].append(value)

aa = list(map(list, dd))
bb = list(map(min, dd.values()))

print(aa, bb, sep='\n'*2)

[[9, 5], [9, 10000], [5, 10000], [10001, 10]]

[19144.85, 8824.73, 23348.02, 40188.8]
```

#### Explanation

There are 3 steps:

1. Create a dictionary mapping each pair of keys to a list of values. Be careful to use `tuple` as keys, which must be hashable.
2. For *unique* keys, just extract your `defaultdict` keys, mapping to `list` so that you have a list of lists instead of list of tuples.
3. For minimum values, use `map` with `min`.

#### Note on ordering

Dictionaries are insertion ordered in Python 3.6+, and this can be relied upon in 3.7+. In earlier versions, you can rely on *consistency* of ordering between `dd.keys` and `dd.values` provided no operations have taken place in between access of keys and values.

Comment: I had started writing a solution using `combination` and `enumerate` and all that jazz ... But this is so much more straightforward. A bit more explanation for novices is welcome though. Basically, create a dictionary with the unique values from `a` mapped to the values from `b` put in a list. Then you can just `list()` the keys of that dictionary and get their `min()` values.

Comment: @BramVanroy, Sure, I've tried to add a bit more explanation.

Comment: Great! Very helpful for everyone. +1